# Proof That $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\left\{x\right\}f´(x)dx=\int_{1}^{n}\left\{x\right\}f´(x)dx$

Tags: integration, summation, euler-maclaurin, ramanujan-summation

I am Reading the following notes: Ramanujan summation of divergent series by B Candelpergher (https://hal.univ-cotedazur.fr/hal-01150208v2/document). There, the author derives the Euler-MacLaurin summation formula in the beginning of the first chapter.
In one of the steps (on page 18 of the file) he states that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}[x]f´(x)dx=\int_{1}^{n}xf´(x)dx+\int_{1}^{n}\left\{x\right\}f´(x)dx$$
$\left\{x\right\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

The first integral on the right side I understand, but the second one involving the fractional part of $x$, I can´t really see how it´s true. In other words, he is saying that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\left\{x\right\}f´(x)dx=\int_{1}^{n}\left\{x\right\}f´(x)dx$$
 Can someone kindly show the proof or the intuition behind it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it!

I took the reverse way to prove it.
$$\int_{1}^{n}\left\{x\right\}f´(x)dx= \int_{1}^{n}(x-\left[x\right])f´(x)dx$$
$$ =\int_{1}^{n}x f´(x)dx    -\int_{1}^{n} \left[x\right]f´(x)dx$$
$$ =\int_{1}^{n}x f´(x)dx    -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1} \left[x\right]f´(x)dx$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1}x f´(x)dx    -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1} \left[x\right]f´(x)dx$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1}(x  - \left[x\right])f´(x)dx$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1}\left\{x\right\}f´(x)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Just write out the sum: \begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_k^{k+1} \text{whatever}\, dx &= \int_1^2 \text{whatever}\, dx + \int_2^3 \text{whatever}\, dx + \cdots + \int_{n-1}^n \text{whatever}\, dx \\
&= \int_1^n \text{whatever}\, dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: ...where $\text{whatever}=\{x\}f´(x)$ :)

Comment: @Connor Harris I tried what you say, but I get the following: $\int_{n-1}^{n} \left\{x\right\}f´(x)dx=\int_{n-1}^{n}(x-\left[x\right])f´(x)dx$ integrating the first integral by parts I get $\int_{n-1}^{n}(x-\left[x\right])f´(x)dx=f(n)-\int_{n-1}^{n}f(x)dx$. summing up all the integrals I got $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\left\{x\right\}f´(x)dx= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)-\int_{1}^{n} f(x)dx$

Comment: Why do you need to do any integrals?